# What type of file should i store huffman results?

Tags: java, algorithm, encoding, huffman-code

I have the tree, the encoded values for the every byte ,the encoded and decoding table, and my encoded file in a binary file for the encoded file, i have two questions, what should i store, only the decoding table and the encoded file should be enough? And in what type of file should i store the decoding table and my encoded file? I'm using java.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a canonical tree, you only need to store the length of the code for each byte, in order by unencoded value. Since the maximum length of a huffman code is the number of distinct unencoded values and the minimum length is 1, each length will fit in a single byte. (the gzip library also huffman encodes the lengths to reduce the overhead even more.)

There is a simple algorithm to generate the full tree from the list of lengths, assuming the codes are canonical.

Actually, there are at least two possible canonical encoding styles. In both cases the codes of a given length have the same order as the original unencoded bytes. In the canonical code described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code), shorter codes are before longer codes (i.e. the *shortest* code is all zeros. But a more common canonical form puts longer codes at the beginning, so that the *longest* code is all zeros. The Wikipedia article includes the algorithm for producing its form of canonical coding; the other form is equally simple.

The advantage of the longest-code-first form is that you can demonstrate that only the last `ceil(log2n)` bits of any code can be non-zero (`n` is the alphabet size); in other words, each code consists of some number of zero bits followed by at most one "byte" of mixed zeros and ones. This property can help make decoding faster.

Comment: but my question is, how can i save both my coded output file and the table which i use to decode it... in the case im not using the canonical codes, such the normal ones that huffman algorithm makes

Comment: Serialize your decoding table and then output the coded bits, I guess. But the canonical table will be a lot shorter, and it's not hard.

Comment: Canonical encoding doesnt work if a letter form an alphabet is missing right ??? for example if you have 'A', 'C', 'D', it wont work like that right ???

Comment: @pedro: that's right, canonical encoding assumes that all symbols occur. You can insert 0's into the length vector to indicate missing symbols, and if you expect that the symbols use form a subrange of the bytes (say, 0x20 through 0x7E, if it were US-ASCII), you could also output the symbol range (two characters) prior to the length vector (still using 0s if necessary).